# Django Rest Framework : Nested Serializer not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have almost tried everything but am not able to reach at the point

**model.py** file

```py
class RecievingImages(models.Model):
     """Original and Masked Images"""
    ....
    name                        = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True, primary_key=True)
    area                        = models.IntegerField()
    number                      = models.IntegerField()
    agency_name                 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='general')
    rawImage                    = models.ImageField(upload_to=imageNameForRawImage,)
    ...

class UpdationImages(models.Model):
    """ Update Image wrt name"""
    ....
    name                        = models.ForeignKey(RecievingImages, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='updated')
    updated_image               = models.ImageField(upload_to=UpdatedImageFolder,)
    updated_image_url           = models.TextField(default='None')
   ....
```

**serializer.py**

```py
class UpdatedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = UpdationImages
    fields = ('name', 'updated_image', 'updated_image_url')

class RecievingImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  updated = UpdatedImageSerializer(many= True, read_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = RecievingImages
    fields = ('updated','name','area','number','agency_name', rawImage)
```

I have used `related_name` in the model and also following the documentation along with that with `many = True`

But still in `serializer.data` `updated` does not show

**views.py**

```py
class MappingSinglePhoto(APIView):
    """ Mapping Single Image """
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            name_of_image = data['name']
            mapped_images_qs = UpdationImages.objects.select_related('name').filter(name = name_of_image)
            for image in mapped_images_qs:
                serializer = RecievingImagesSerializer(instance = image)
                pdb.set_trace()
                serializer.data
            # return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

**NOTE**
if I use `depth=1` then it's working fine, but I am not looking for all the fields that depth displays.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: seems like you are missing the ***`Meta`*** class in your serializer

Comment: I have updated in the question, there was an error in copy and pasting from code.

Comment: You are passing **`UpdationImages`** instance to **`RecievingImagesSerializer`**, which is expecting a **`RecievingImages`** instance

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: Okay @ArakkalAbu I got your point, but the object is present in both the models

Comment: Oh man! you were right, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ArakkalAbu

There was a problem in query **views.py**

```
class MappingSinglePhoto(APIView):
    """ Mapping Single Image """
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            name_of_image = data['name']
            mapped_images_qs = RecievingImages.objects.filter(name = name_of_image)
            for image in mapped_images_qs:
                serializer = RecievingImagesSerializer(instance = image)
                pdb.set_trace()
                serializer.data
            # return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```